# row count on inner join

Tags: mysql, count, inner-join

ok i've been trying for 2 days to figure this out. I have 2 tables

- Organization_dep

  - id
  - orgid
  - depname
- organization_dep_users

  - id
  - orgid
  - depid
  - userid

I want to list the count of user ids from the departments of the organizations.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this:

```
SELECT 
    b.depname, count(a.id)
FROM organization_dep_users a 
INNER JOIN Organization_dep b ON a.depid = b.id
GROUP BY b.depname;
```

### Edit:

Thanks for Barmar for additional details.

Comment: The question is not clear. The relationship may be `ON a.depid = b.id AND a.orgid = b.orgid`

Comment: Shouldn't you select `b.depname`, so you know which department each count belongs to?

Comment: is "depname" unique? if not you might want to group by id instead.

Comment: The question is unclear. I think she's referring to "from the departments of the organizations" = `b.depname`.